# Return with ternary expression breaks foreach loop on first iteration

Tags: php, foreach, return, conditional-operator

Ok, i tested what follows and i'll just let you know what i discovered:

```
echo ('-1' < 0) ? 'true' : 'false'; // will echo "true"
echo ('1' > 0) ? 'true' : 'false'; // will echo "true"
# Notice that '-1' and '1' are strings
```

Now let's take an array, coming from the database after filtering all the result in order to get only rows with `UID = 1`.

```
$this->a = array(
    [0] => array(
        'UID' => '1',
        'PID' => '91',
        'Amount' => '-1'
    ),
    [1] => array(
        'UID' => '1',
        'PID' => '92',
        'Amount' => '1'
    ),
    [2] => array(
        'UID' => '1',
        'PID' => '93',
        'Amount' => '1'
    )
);
```

Now i want to create a function `posAmount($PID)` that returns `true` if `'Amount' > 0` or `false` if `'Amount' < 0`. (Notice: Amount = 0 is something i don't really care). Also i'd like to write as similar function called `negAmount($PID)` that returns the exactely opposite of the first. I'd like, now, to introduce you to my twin functions:

```
public function posAmount($pid)
{
    foreach ($this->a as $a)
    {
        if (count($this->a) == 0) { return false; }
        return ($a['PID'] == $pid and $a['Amount'] > 0) ? true : false;
    }
}

public function negAmount($pid)
{
    foreach ($this->a as $a)
    {

        if (count($this->a) == 0) { return false; }
        return ($a['PID'] == $pid and $a['Amount'] < 0) ? true : false;
    }
}
```

The cool fact is that, regarding the first array (which, i checked with `var_dump()` keeps its nature trough the entire script):

```
$istance->negAmount(91); // Returns true, as expected
$istance->posAmount(92); // Returns false, as NOT expected.
# Why do God wants me to get mad?
```

Comment: Must be this line: `if (count($this->votes) == 0) { return false; }`

Comment: `return ($a['PID'] == $pid and $a['Amount'] < 0) ? true : false` could be written as `return ($a['PID'] == $pid and $a['Amount'] < 0)` and why do you call  `if (count($this->votes) == 0) { return false; }` in every cycles iteration? That's a bad practice.

Comment: @BoltClock, no, that was an typo. Sorry for that.

Comment: You have just discovered one reason why weak and dynamic (they're seperate, *I know*, but both play their part here) typing can suck ;)

Comment: The real thing that got me mad is that the first (negAmount) works perfectly (in a template context also), and the latter (posAmount) doesn't: They are the same... it's crazy. I lost the last 2 hours trying to figuring out what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks for correcting the typo.  I updated my answer to include working code with an explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are always returning on the first iteration of the foreach loop.  You should rewrite the functions like this:

```
public function negAmount($pid) {
    if (count($this->a) == 0) { return false; }
    foreach ($this->a as $a) {
        if ($a['PID'] == $pid) {
            if ($a['Amount'] < 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public function posAmount($pid) {
    if (count($this->a) == 0) { return false; }
    foreach ($this->a as $a) {
        if ($a['PID'] == $pid) {
            if ($a['Amount'] > 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This function would keep looping after the appropriate array value has already been checked before returning false.  This wouldn't be much of a difference if the data size is small, but with a large data set this could have big performance problems.  It is more efficient to do the ternary operator when PID matches and return true or false as soon as the match is found.

Comment: @Chris Big problems?  PHP can execute tens of thousands of foreach-loops (obviously not empirical data, but relatively accurate) in a matter of a blink of an eye.

Comment: this is your answer. You need to first test that the PID matches AND THEN test Amount. Right now you test for 0 count, and then return true false on the first array index, exiting the function.

Comment: Nevertheless, it is bad practice to iterate unnecessarily over an array when you could have either returned a value or called `break` to stop the loop when the loops purpose has been served.  Why write code with a potential bomb inside it when you can avoid the issue completely with better logic?

Comment: @Chris, you must not have seen the `return true;` inside the loop.

Comment: Instead of being snarky, consider what I am saying.  You must not have read what I said.  If the return will be FALSE, it has to loop over the entire array to ever get to that point - even after it has already determined that it will not be returning TRUE.  The flaw is the combination of the $pid-matching logic and the logic for the `amount` array value being less than or greater than zero.  If the return is TRUE, the function works fine.  If it will be false, the function has an inefficiency that can easily be avoided.You are taking it personally, I think, when it is not personal.

Comment: @Chris the OP never said `$PID` was unique.  What if there is more than one?

Comment: Updated to at least evaluate the value of `amount` only when the `$PID` is matched.

Comment: It is a fair assumption to make, given the other data presented.  Look, if you're offended that I tried to give you a hand, keep it bro.  I am not very interested in debating such a trivial matter.  Good job. (ps: your edit has exactly the same flaw.)

Comment: @Chris I believe you read into my words far beyond what I intend.  Inflection is hard to imply when reading text.  I'm just stating the facts, plainly.  Seriously, I'm not offended.

Answer (score 2):

<del>May just be a typo in your demo code, but `posAmount` method is looping `$this->a`, whereas the other is looping `$this->votes`</del> - OP corrected

You've got some odd things in your code.  Why are you checking the count of `$this->a` from within a `foreach` loop?  It would make more sense to check the count before you start looping.

Also, you've got some logic errors in your comparison.  You're only comparing the first iteration through the loop... it will either return true or false for the first index of the array and never even look at the others.  You'll want to match the PID in the loop before you compare - and return - any thing.  Like so:

```
public function posAmount($pid)
{
    if (count($this->a) == 0) { return false; }
    foreach ($this->votes as $a) {
        if ($a['PID'] == $pid)
        return $a['Amount'] > 0 ? true : false;
    }
    return false;
}

public function posAmount($pid)
{
    if (count($this->a) == 0) { return false; }
    foreach ($this->votes as $a) {
        if ($a['PID'] == $pid)
        return $a['Amount'] < 0 ? true : false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: +1 for explanation, but the accepted answer goes to @Stephen who got it for first.

Comment: `return $a['Amount'] < 0 ? true : false;` is redundant.  just use `return $a['Amount'] < 0;`

Comment: Duly noted and acknowledged, however, I prefer to use a ternary for clarity of intent.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're trying to compare a string to an int without trying to convert it. Change `$a['Amount']` to `(int)$a['Amount']` and see what happens.

Comment: As shown in the snippet at the very top, this is not the case as PHP does type conversion automatically.

Comment: PHP's loose typing does not require casting before such comparison - type is not the issue here.

Comment: Tried, but nothing changed. Anyway it should work (see first lines) even with strings.

Answer (score 0):

So here you iterate $this->a:

```
public function posAmount($pid)
{
    foreach ($this->a as $a)
```

But here $this->votes:

```
public function posAmount($pid)
{
    foreach ($this->a as $a)
```

Typo or what...